# How to load a zip file (containing shp) from s3 bucket to Geopandas?

Tags: amazon-s3, zip, geojson, shapefile, geopandas

I zipped name.shp, name.shx, name.dbf files and uploaded them into a AWS s3 bucket. So now, i wanna load this zip file and convert the contained shapefile into a GeoDataFrame of geopandas.

I can do it perfectly if the file is a zipped geojson instead of zipped shapefile.

```py
import io
import boto3
import geopandas as gpd
import zipfile

cliente = boto3.client("s3", aws_access_key_id=ak, aws_secret_access_key=sk)

bucket_name = 'bucketname'
object_key = 'myfolder/locations.zip'

bytes_buffer = io.BytesIO()
cliente.download_fileobj(Bucket=bucket_name, Key=object_key, Fileobj=bytes_buffer)
geojson = bytes_buffer.getvalue()

with zipfile.ZipFile(bytes_buffer) as zi:
    with zi.open("locations.shp") as file:
        print(gpd.read_file(file.read().decode('ISO-8859-9')))
```

I got this error:

> ç­¤íEÀ¡ËÆ3À: No such file or directory

Answer (score 3):

Basically `geopandas` package allows to read files directly from S3. And as mentioned in the answer above it allows to read `zip` files also. So below you can see the code which will read zip file from s3 without downloading it. You need to enter `zip+s3://` in the beginning, then add the path in S3.

`geopandas.read_file(f'zip+s3://bucket-name/file.zip')`

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Comment: As a warning with `fiona==1.8.17` I got a curl error, and an updated fix it.
`pip install -U fiona`

Comment: I get "CPLE_HttpResponseError....CURL error: SSL certificate problem: self signed certificate in certificate chain" as expected since we're not passing any keys or certs.

Comment: Also `geopandas.read_file` passes **kwargs to `fiona.open` or `fiona.BytesCollection`. Maybe the bytes buffer with downloaded fileobj would suffice in `fiona.collection.BytesCollection(bytesbuf, **kwds)`?

Comment: From fiona docs, I suspect `geopandas.read_file` might slow depending on use-case: "Fiona trades memory and speed for simplicity...Fiona copies vector data from the data source to Python objects"

Answer (score 1):

You can read zip directly, no need to use zipfile. You need all parts of Shapefile, not just .shp itself. That is why it works with geojson. You just need to pass it with `zip:///`. So instead of

```
gpd.read_file('path/file.shp')
```

You go with

```
gpd.read_file('zip:///path/file.zip')
```

I am not familiar enough with `boto3` to know at which point you actually have this path, but I think it will help.

Comment: Thank you. Working with zipped .shp in s3 was not easy because that format contains two other related files, and the geopandas can't recognize them. So, i just  change the format to gpkg.

Answer (score 1):

I do not know if it can be of any help, but I faced a similar problem recently, though I only wanted to read the `.shp` with `fiona`. I ended up like others zipping the relevant `shp`, `dbf`, `cpg` and `shx` on the bucket.

And to read from the bucket, I do like so:

```py
from io import BytesIO
from pathlib import Path
from typing import List
from typing import Union

import boto3
from fiona.io import ZipMemoryFile
from pydantic import BaseSettings
from shapely.geometry import Point
from shapely.geometry import Polygon
import fiona

class S3Configuration(BaseSettings):
    """
    S3 configuration class
    """
    s3_access_key_id: str = ''
    s3_secret_access_key: str = ''
    s3_region_name: str = ''
    s3_endpoint_url: str = ''
    s3_bucket_name: str = ''
    s3_use: bool = False

S3_CONF = S3Configuration()
S3_STR = 's3'
S3_SESSION = boto3.session.Session()
S3 = S3_SESSION.resource(
    service_name=S3_STR,
    aws_access_key_id=S3_CONF.s3_access_key_id,
    aws_secret_access_key=S3_CONF.s3_secret_access_key,
    endpoint_url=S3_CONF.s3_endpoint_url,
    region_name=S3_CONF.s3_region_name,
    use_ssl=True,
    verify=True,
) 
BUCKET = S3_CONF.s3_bucket_name
CordexShape = Union[Polygon, List[Polygon], List[Point]]
ZIP_EXT = '.zip'


def get_shapefile_data(file_path: Path, s3_use: S3_CONF.s3_use) -> CordexShape:
    """
    Retrieves the shapefile content associated to the passed file_path (either on disk or on S3).
    file_path is a .shp file.
    """
    if s3_use:
        return load_zipped_shp(get_s3_object(file_path.with_suffix(ZIP_EXT)), file_path)
    return load_shp(file_path)


def get_s3_object(file_path: Path) -> bytes:
    """
    Retrieve as bytes the content associated to the passed file_path
    """
    return S3.Object(bucket_name=BUCKET, key=forge_key(file_path)).get()['Body'].read()


def forge_key(file_path: Path) -> str:
    """
    Edit this code at your convenience to forge the bucket key out of the passed file_path
    """
    return str(file_path.relative_to(*file_path.parts[:2]))


def load_shp(file_path: Path) -> CordexShape:
    """
    Retrieve a list of Polygons stored at file_path location
    """
    with fiona.open(file_path) as shape:
        parsed_shape = list(shape)
    return parsed_shape


def load_zipped_shp(zipped_data: bytes, file_path: Path) -> CordexShape:
    """
    Retrieve a list of Polygons stored at file_path location
    """
    with ZipMemoryFile(BytesIO(zipped_data)) as zip_memory_file:
        with zip_memory_file.open(file_path.name) as shape:
            parsed_shape = list(shape)
    return parsed_shape
```

There is quite a lot of code, but the first part is very helpful to easily use a minio proxy for local devs (just have to change the .env).

The key to solve the issue for me was the use of fiona not so well documented (in my opinion) but life saver (in my case :)) `ZipMemoryFile`